# Laravel permission denied errors

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I made a website and the website got error on the server . But there is no problem on my local.
When I send code to git , I got error file put content . 
When I use php artisan view:cache problem solved but some hours later I got error file put content permission denied automatically.

I investigated for this problem and I found `chmod -R 777` command but I got this error again . 
I don't know how to solve this problem .

May you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you get? What exactly did you `chmod -R 777`?

Comment: Like this :

file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/website.com/laravel_folder/website/storage/framework/views/b39445395663c48f23ad5a05e1f7264e53b71044.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: I used chmod -R 777 after that i thought problem was solved but i got error again.

Comment: Did you change or update any of the files before the error came back?

Answer (score -1):

Try this..Whichever way you set it up, then you need to give read and write permissions to the webserver for storage, cache

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Why `bootstrap/cache`?

Comment: sometimes it needs to give permission to cache .then it good to give it permission earlier